# How do you make a terminal window run in the background on mac

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Can someone help me I have been trying to make a program run in the background.

Comment: This site is not intended to provide free solutions but rather help users solve specific problems they may be having. With that in mind, you are more likely to get an answer if you provide some context for what you have tried and something you have specifically had issues with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bash shell, try

```
thecommand &
```

The & signals the shell to run that command in the background.